# "watch" command to notify on newly created files on linux

Tags: shell-scripting

watch command to notify on newly created files on linux

How to modify the below command to notify on creating a new file to /usr/local/mydir/ by linux user john ?

```
watch -d 'ls -l /usr/local/mydir/ | fgrep john'
```

ie I want to continually monitor and call an another script if any new file is created to /usr/local/mydir/.

As In production I cannot go for any tool instead of shell script. So can help me with shell scripting solution ?

Comment: why not just use iwatch ? http://iwatch.sourceforge.net/index.html . works for us.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of constantly pulling a directory this way, maybe try to use the `inotify` subsystem, which is designed for this purpose. For user space tools, have a look at the [`inotify-tools`](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki/).

Answer (score 6):

`inotify` suggested by SvenW is an excellent choice for this.

Just to be different: Alternative, more complete way for this kind of stuff is to use kernel audit subsystem and `auditd`. Just install `auditd` if it's not already installed and then use `auditctl`, in your case

```
auditctl -w /usr/local/mydir/ -p wa -F uid=john -k johnschangedfiles
```

would do.

Then you can run a report and see a very detailed log of what happened and when:

```
ausearch -f /usr/local/mydir/
```

This produces results similar to this:

```
time->Fri Feb  3 12:45:19 2012
type=PATH msg=audit(1328265919.961:11): item=0 name="/tmp/test/foo" inode=1839907 dev=fd:00 mode=0100664 ouid=500 ogid=500 rdev=00:00 obj=unconfined_u:object_r:user_tmp_t:s0
type=CWD msg=audit(1328265919.961:11):  cwd="/tmp"
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1328265919.961:11): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=yes exit=3 a0=7fffa6f4262e a1=941 a2=1b6 a3=3136fb0d0c items=1 ppid=12414 pid=23531 auid=500 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=pts1 ses=686 comm="touch" exe="/bin/touch" subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 key="jpikkschangedfiles"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on using just standard tools, a script like the following might help:

```
#!/bin/bash
ls -l /usr/local/mydir | grep john > /tmp/watchfile

while true; do
   sleep 10
   ls -l /usr/local/mydir | grep john > /tmp/watchfile2
   diff -q /tmp/watchfile /tmp/watchfile2 > /dev/null
   if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
       echo "File list changed" 
       exit ;
   fi
   cp /tmp/watchfile2 /tmp/watchfile
done
```

Replace the `echo`line with your desired action and remove the `exit` line if you want to run this script continuously.

Note: This will act on any modification of the directory listing, even if files just get updated, not added.

Comment: Thanks fro your response ... But if any file get deleted from [/usr/local/mydir] this also will differ the watchfile and watchfile2. I want to do the  desired action only when the new file is created in [/usr/local/mydir].

Comment: Yes. Getting this right and fitting for every situation is difficult (but possible). Therefore, I again suggest to use tools that are designed for this purpose.